# Unable to restore pre-trained model using tf.restore

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am unable to restore the pretrained model using tf.restore 
I have added the models in the models directory and given that only as the directory name in the restore command. 
"Key variable not found in checkpoint" is the main error.
Save:

```
savePath = saver.save(sess, "/home/dakshita/friends/models/pretrained_seq2seq.ckpt", global_step=i)
```

Restore:

```
with tf.Session()as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/home/dakshita/friends/models/pretrained_seq2seq.ckpt-25000.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/home/dakshita/friends/models'))
```

Error:

```
2018-07-18 16:37:25.045960: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1318] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:184 : Not found: Key Variable not found in checkpoint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key Variable not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dakshita/PycharmProjects/LSTM/DictCreation.py", line 429, in <module>
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/home/dakshita/friends/models'))
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1802, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key Variable not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2', defined at:
  File "/home/dakshita/PycharmProjects/LSTM/DictCreation.py", line 427, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1338, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1347, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1384, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 835, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 472, in _AddRestoreOps
    restore_sequentially)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 886, in bulk_restore
    return io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, dtypes)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1463, in restore_v2
    shape_and_slices=shape_and_slices, dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/dakshita/miniconda2/envs/heymojo3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key Variable not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. It is difficult to tell whether it is actually your code or a sketch. For example, you have sees instead of sess. Is this in your code?

Comment: You redefine your saver instance. You don't have to do it, so you can savely remove `saver = tf.train.Saver()`.